# Analytic equivalence

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider the family of germs (at $0$) given by $C_{\lambda} = \{ (x,y) \in \Bbb C^2 : x^4 + 2\lambda y^2x^2 + y^4 = 0 \} $

Dimca in his book about singularity claims that they are analytically not equivalent but topologically equivalent. I think I understand why they are not analytically equivalent as not all members of the family are irreducible curves. I am not sure why they are topologically equivalent, I would be glad if someone could write some details. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @reuns Thanks I corrected, but it is irreducible unless for some values of $\lambda$

Comment: It is not irreducible as a polynomial of $\overline{\mathbb{C}(y)}[x]$

Comment: @reuns : I don't think it is relevant for my problem, as I would like to see why these curves are topologically equivalent.